# Trying to make a TEdit/TMemo similar to other search bars or edits on the web

Tags: delphi

I'm currently busy with my PAT (Practical Assessment Task).

I'm trying to figure out how to make my `TMemo` similar to search bars on the web.

For example: "|Enter Search or web address"

I want the "|", or vertical bar or whatever you call it, to move to the beginning of the TMemo when I click on it and I want the "Enter Search or web address" to stay there when there is nothing that is typed, but once I type it has to disappear.

I hope this makes sense, because it's really hard to explain. Just look at your usual browser search bar and start typing and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: and the "|" is called cursor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(user_interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `TEdit` and fill out the [`TextHint`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.TextHint) property to achieve what you want.

Comment: Is there a property that specifies that the `TextHint` must stay visible when the control gets focus because on my side it dissappears the moment the control gets focus?

Comment: In my experience, when you click in the search bar, the prompt text disappears; it doesn't stay there once you click in the box.  It does return if you change the focus without typing anything.  As such, this answer appears to match the normal behaviour

Comment: @BlurrySterk the underlying [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setcuebanner) API does have an option to do what you want, but the`TextHint` property does not use that option.